# How to detect auto audio flash on the page?

Tags: javascript, flash

Is is possible to detect within JavaScript of Flash if there is auto audio another flash object (mostly ad) on the page?

Answer (score 0):

I think yes, because youtube player stop all other movies and audios (even if those players are on other pages) and then starts playing the movie...
Search on youtube player using [swf decompiler](http://www.sothink.com/product/flashdecompiler/index.htm)...

Comment: I suppose youtube defined an interface and maybe even provides an sdk for any ads that are intended to go on youtube.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible. Even if it were, ads usually come from other servers, so same origin policy would prohibit accessing those flash files.